# Microsoft Surface laptop not connecting to external screens

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, microsoft-surface

I have Windows 10 pro on a Microsoft Surface Laptop. One of the main things I do with my laptop is connected it to my TV or my external monitor via HDMI/Mini Display port. As of now, my laptop is not even detecting the monitors connected to it. I have tried just about everything, from restarting, to uninstalling/updating my display adapter driver, to trying different cords, to resetting windows, etc. One of the primary functions of my laptop is for watching movies on my TV, so this issue is very frustrating. I have had this problem with Windows 10 before on a different laptop, but resetting windows always fixed it.

*Edit (Further information):*

The laptop was connecting to these screens no problem, but it stopped all of sudden. Nothing that I know of happened between the time it was working and the time it stopped. Nothing that would affect anything like that.

By "resetting" windows, I mean reinstalling it, while keeping all of my files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used Windows "Fresh Start" tool to reinstall Windows. Really simple.

It is located under "Device Performance & Health".